# Conditional java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Webstart application

Tags: java, java-web-start

We have a webstart swing application running on our multiple remote desktop servers for a lot of customers. Suddenly, on one of our servers the customers started getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. Not on startup, the applications starts up fine, but when doing specific tasks, eg sending a mail through our software, it popups up in the console like this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pos/MailSenderInterface
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    ......
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pos.MailSenderInterface
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 56 more
```

The problem is, this only happens on ONE of our servers. On all the other servers the webstart application runs just fine! But on this single terminal server, I get the error, even though the java version is the same, and the link to the jnlp-file is the same.
I have of course tried deleting temporary internet files in the java control panel, to no avail.
I then started toying around a bit, and found out something very strange.
Our customers start the application from an icon pointing to a batch-file in c:\drift
This batchfile only contains the following:

```
@start javaws http://ourserver/ourapplication.jnlp
```

Typing the link outside the batch-file gives the same error. Then I typed cd .. so that my current path was c:\ instead of c:\drift and started javaws from there. And surprise, no errors! I then tried cd drift again and the error occured again. I have tried this many times now, with the same result. So somehow the path from WHERE I start javaws have something to say for if I get the NoClassDefFoundError or not. But neither c:\ or c:\drift contains any .jar-files (although subdirectories may). I am very perplexed by this. What on earth is wrong? Our java version is 1.7.0_67

Comment: check if the required jar is in the class path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! The path c:\drift\ actually had a directory "pos" from a couple of years back, with an old version of MailSender.class but with no MailSenderInterface.class Deleting this directory solved the problem. :-) 
(Remember that the error was about a missing pos/MailSenderInterface)
Apparently the newest javaws in java 1.7.0_67 tries to load classes from a subdirectory of the place where you started javaws if such a directory is found, instead of loading the files from the correctly downloaded jar-files.